# Display count of task for each id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have page where i display list of tasks (with Jquery DataTable) and i want display Employee name with count of thire tasks. for example:

Smith (2) | John (1) | Thomas (1)

Tables:

AssignName:

[image: assignname]

Tasks (AssignId as ForeignKey):

[image: tasks]

Here what i did :

Here i get List of tasks and select some properties:

```
var Taskslist = db.Tasks.Select(g =>  new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup
                { 
                    OpgaveServicesId = g.Id,
                    Opgaver = g.Opgaver,
                    Opgaveid = g.Id,
                    Opretteaf = g.Opretteaf,
                    OpretteDato = g.OpretteDato,

                }).AsEnumerable();
```

Her iterating over the results to get count each id:

```
foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    var AssignCount = db.AssignName.Where(c => c.Id == item.Assingid)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Select(b => new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup { Assingid = b.Count(), EmployeeNames= b.Key });
                }
```

Put all code together (for simplicity i remove unneeded code):

```
public JsonResult ListofTasks() {
var Taskslist = db.Tasks.Select(g =>  new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup
            { 
                OpgaveServicesId = g.Id,
                Opgaver = g.Opgaver,
                Opgaveid = g.Id,
                Opretteaf = g.Opretteaf,
                OpretteDato = g.OpretteDato,

            }).AsEnumerable();

            var result = Taskslist.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                var AssignCount = db.AssignName.Where(c => c.Id == item.Assingid)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                    .Select(b => new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup { Assingid = b.Count(), EmployeeNames= b.Key });
            }
            JsonResult json = Json(new { data = result, draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalrows, recordsFiltered = totalrowsefterfiltering }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return json;
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<ItemGroup> ItemGroups { get; set; }
public class ItemGroup
{

    public ItemGroup()
    {

    }

    public int OpgaveServicesId { get; set; }
    public string Opgaver { get; set; }
    public string Opretteaf { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OpretteDato { get; set; }
    public int Opgaveid { get; set; }
    public int OpgaveSmartid { get; set; }
    public string Opgavestatus { get; set; }
    public int? Assingid { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNames { get; set; }
}
```

In the end when I check the results both **Assingid** and **EmployeeNames** are `null`. Can anyone please help me :)

Comment: I have one suggestion here. Remove `Opretteaf ` column from the Tasks table, it's redundant

Comment: `var AssignCount =...` - it seems that you just create  variable inside your foreach loop which will be discarded.

Comment: Also can you please add the entites classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of `AssignCount` variable is limited to foreach loop, that is the reason you are getting `Assingid` and `EmployeeNames` as a null at the end of program.

To fix this issue, store each `AssignCount` to the list, so that you can access all counts out of `foreach` loop

```
...
//Define list of List of ItemGroup, as AssignCount is of type List<ItemGroup>
List<List<ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup>> itemGroups = new List<List<ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup>>();   
foreach (var item in result)
{
    var AssignCount = db.AssignName.Where(c => c.Id == item.Assingid)
          .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
          .Select(b => new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup { Assingid = b.Count(), EmployeeNames= b.Key })
          .ToList(); //Convert To List
   
    itemGroups.Add(AssignCount);  //Add each `AssignCount` to itemGroups
}

//Now list of AssignCount(s) is(are) accessible outside foreach loop
...
```

Comment: Yes, i did but i get error : Cannot Convert Collections.Generic.List<ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup> to ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup

Comment: var itemGroups = new List<ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup>();
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    var AssignCount = db.AssignName.Where(c => c.Id == item.Assingid)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Select(b => new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup { Assingid = b.Count(), EmployeeName = b.Key });

                    itemGroups.Add(itemGroups); <--here i get error ,
                }

Comment: Not Problem :) error goes away. but there is an issue hope you can help me :) when i have this line  JsonResult json = Json(new { data = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) - Assingid and EmployeeNames are null, but when i change this line to  JsonResult json = Json(new { data = itemGroups} - Assingid and EmployeeNames are not null , but i dont have any the others properties its just going to return Assingid and EmployeeNames and not the others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216327/discussion-between-prasad-telkikar-and-the-professor-and-the-madman).

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is doing the counting and assigning it to the variable `AssignCount` which only exists in the scope of the `for` loop. You need to capture that result in a variable that is outside the scope of the loop to pass that along to your view.

Something like:

```
var itemGroups = new List<ItemGroup>();
foreach (var item in result)
{
     var AssignCount = db.AssignName.Where(c => c.Id == item.Assingid)
                         .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Select(b => new ServicetasksVM.ItemGroup { Assingid = b.Count(), EmployeeNames= b.Key });
     itemGroups.Add(AssignCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable `AssignCount`  is local in the `foreach` loop. better create collection outside of the loop and keep on adding to it inside the loop.